# How do I partially clean a build based on my current Cargo.lock?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

This question is mainly about caching on a CI, because as we restore and save the cache, if the `Cargo.lock` is updated, or the dependencies themselves, the `target` cache gets more and more stale builds that are no longer needed. But this is also relevant for my local copy of the project, that over the time accumulates builds that are no longer needed.

So, given the toolchain triplet, its version, and the dependencies of the project with all features enabled, locked to an specific version, how do I clear all the builds that are not defined by this information?

Comment: You can identify changes in Cargo.lock in CI and if it was changed clean the target directory (before building). Locally you can just know when you change it. I don't know a tool that can do exactly what you want.